# Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality (Probability) and the Fundamental Bridge

Tags: probability, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

In a section on the **Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (a marginal bound on a joint expectation)**, my textbook, *Introduction to Probability, Second Edition*, by Blitzstein and Hwang, presents the following example:

> **Example 10.1.3** (Second moment method). Let $X$ be a nonnegative r.v., and suppose that we want an upper bound on $P(X = 0)$. For example, $X$ could be the number of questions that Fred gets wrong on an exam (then $P(X = 0)$ is the probability of Fred getting perfect score), or $X$ could be the number of pairs of people at a party with the same birthday (then $P(X = 0)$ is the probability of no birthday matches). Note that
>
> $$X = XI(X > 0),$$
>
> where $I(X > 0)$ is the indicator of $X > 0$. This is true since if $X = 0$, then both sides are $0$, while if $X > 0$ then both sides are $X$. By Cauchy-Schwarz,
>
> $$E(X) = E(XI(X > 0)) \le \sqrt{E(X^2) E(I(X > 0))}.$$
>
> Rearranging this and using the fundamental bridge, we have
>
> $$P(X > 0) \ge \dfrac{(EX)^2}{E(X^2)},$$
>
> or equivalently,
>
> $$P(X = 0) \le \dfrac{Var(X)}{E(X^2)}.$$

The **fundamental bridge (between probability and expectation)** is the fact that there is a one-to-one correspondence between events and indicator r.v.s, and the probability of an event $A$ is the expected value of its indicator r.v. $I_A$:

$$P(A) = E(I_A).$$

Given this, we can get the first result as follows:

$$\begin{align} &E(X) \le \sqrt{E(X^2)E(I(X > 0))} \\ &\Rightarrow E(X)^2 \le E(X^2)E(I(X > 0)) = E(X^2)P(X > 0) \\ &\Rightarrow \dfrac{E(X)^2}{E(X^2)} \le P(X > 0) \end{align}$$

But how does one derive the second result? In particular, I'm confused as to where the $Var(X)$ came from? I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(X=0)=1-P(X>0) \leq 1-\frac {(EX)^{2}} {EX^{2}}=\frac {EX^{2}-(EX)^{2}} {EX^{2}} =\frac {var (X)} {EX^{2}}$.

Comment: Oh, I see: We have on the left-hand side that $$E(XI(X > 0)) = P(X > 0) = 1 - P(X = 0) \Rightarrow 1 - P(X > 0) = P(X = 0).$$

Comment: Yes,but you wrote $EXI(X>0)$ instead of $EI(X>0)$.

Comment: Hmm? But it *is* $E(XI(X > 0))$?

Comment: And for the right-hand side, we have that $$E(X^2) E(I(X > 0)) = E(X^2) P(X > 0) = E(X^2) [1 - P(X = 0)],$$ by the same reasoning as for the LHS.

Comment: If $X$ takes the values $1$ and $2$ with probability $\frac  1 2$ each then $EXI(X>0)=(1)(\frac  1 2)+(2)(\frac  1 2)=1.5$ but $P(X>0)=1$.

Comment: Oh, I made the mistake of thinking that $E(XI(X > 0)) = P(X > 0)$. Is that what you're referring to? Then what happens to $E(XI(X > 0))$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That is what I meant.